# Scatter chart plot on border if values are outside the bounderies

Tags: highcharts, scatter

I am developing a scatter chart (with 4-quadrants). I would like each points in the series to lie either inside the quadrants (if the values are with-in the x-axis and y-axis boundaries) or be plotted just on the axis boundary if the values are out of the axis range.

Attached a jsfiddle where the second point in each series lies outside the boundary, but are invisible (as expected), but I would like these points to be plotted on the boundary line 100 or -100 in my case and still show the tool-tip with the actual value.

http://jsfiddle.net/raghuromp/xjzd9k02/2/

```
var series1Data = [ [71,33], [75, -105]];
var series2Data = [ [80,-59], [101, 56]];
```

Can someone help me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [load event](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) like this:

```js
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.series.length; i++) {
        var data = this.series[i].data
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
          data[j].actualXValue = data[j].x
          data[j].actualYValue = data[j].y
          if (data[j].x > 100) {
            data[j].x = 100
          }
          if (data[j].x < -100) {
            data[j].x = -100
          }
          if (data[j].y > 100) {
            data[j].y = 100
          }
          if (data[j].y < -100) {
            data[j].y = -100
          }
        }
        this.series[i].update({
          data: data
        })
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

This goes through all the points present, changes their value if they are beyond +-100, but keeps the real value in a separate parameter.

Then, changing the tooltip to reflect the actual values, can be done like this:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
        this.point.actualXValue + ': ' + this.point.actualYValue;
  }
},
```

**Working JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/nsdk40ez/21/